# I can not compare a variable with a string String in SPservices

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, office365, spservices

I want to hide the Ribbon in Office 365 SharePoint according to the group that this user was able to extract the group to which the user belongs, I can not compare it with a string does not fall within the IF, to hide the ribbon this is my code if I can help please thanks.

```
var Nombre_Grup="";
$(document).ready(function()
    $().SPServices(
        { //inicio de SPservices 
            operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
            userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),  
            async: false, 
            completefunc: function(xData, Status)
            {
                $(xData.responseXML).find("Group").each(function()
                                                        {
                                                            Nombre_Grup = $(this).attr("Name");

                                                        });
            }
        });
    console.log(Nombre_Grup);
    if(d == "Usuarios de distribución rápida")
    {
        $('#s4-ribbonrow').hide();
    }           
    else if (Nombre_Grup == "Diseñadores")
    {
        $('#s4-ribbonrow').show();
    }  
   });
```

Comment: Where do you set the variable `d`? Shouldn't that be `Nombre_Grup`? Also, you're missing the `{` at the beginning of the function.

Comment: I'm sorry is  `Nombre_Grup`
but I can not compare with the chain

Comment: Does console.log show the correct value?

Comment: Maybe there's whitespace around it, try `Nombre_Grup.trim()`.

Comment: Barmar worked thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
Nombre_Grup = $(this).attr("Name").trim();
```

to remove any surrounding whitespace in the field.